# Left margin minipage two figures

Tags: margins, minipage

I have a `minipage` with two figures, the problem is, that I want to have them shifted to the left, so the left margin should be smaller, the code of my `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
\centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{simplevaralv.png}}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz]{VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz}
\label{sva}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
\centering
 \centerline{ \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{simplevarbasf.png}}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Basf]{VaR assuming normal distribution, BASF}
\label{svb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

And I want to have it shifted to the left, how can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a box and trick latex to think that the box has zero width and then center it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe} %% just to show frames.

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz]{VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz}
\label{sva}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Basf]{VaR assuming normal distribution, BASF}
\label{svb}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can also be done with `adjustbox` package.

Answer (score 8):

A `\hspace{}` is enough to do the trick. Add this in front of the first minipage (how much space depends on the particular case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\hspace{-1.6cm}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth} %%% ADDED HERE %%%
\centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz]{VaR assuming normal distribution, Allianz}
\label{sva}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
\centering
 \centerline{ \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}}
  \caption[VaR assuming normal distribution, Basf]{VaR assuming normal distribution, BASF}
\label{svb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]